# How to get latest message in chat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to retrieve the most recent message in a chat room and I am using React Native. I have stored all the chat messages in the chat state, however, my current code only returns the second to last message. Can anyone assist me in retrieving the latest message in the room?

```
 const GetLastMessage = chat.length > 0 ? chat[chat.length - 1] : "New Message";
```

Comment: You should give more code. It appears that the problem isn't in the way you're getting the message from the array but the way your message state updates. It's very often a source of bugs in react.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this is its retrieving second last msg is your component state is not updated yet and you are already getting that msg.Make sure a point where you are getting updated state and then retrieve a last msg.